# question about legendre symbol

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have a question about Legendre symbol or I think that we will use Legendre symbol I am not sure,because I tried to apply the definition of Legendre symbol, quadratic reciprocity and also the properties of Legendre symbol but I could not succeed... Perhaps that question needs something else than Legenndre symbol.

Here is the question:

```
"Calculate (3/10) and also calculate (2/15)"
```

Thanks for your help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not the Legendre symbol, but the Kronnecker symbol, and we have
$$
\left( \frac{3}{10}\right)=\left( \frac{3}{2}\right)\left( \frac{3}{5}\right)=-1\cdot (-1)=1.
$$
Do the same with $\left( \frac{2}{15}\right)$.

Comment: thanks dietrich burde.i did not think jacobi.

Comment: Here $(3/2)=-1$ is the Kronnecker symbol $(a/2)$. The Legendre symbol $(a/p)$ is for primes $p\neq 2$.